# Is an object on a parabolic path always under constant acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

We know that an object under constant acceleration follows a parabolic path (as long as the acceleration and velocity are not parallel), but is the converse also true?
What's the easiest way to prove the answer?

Comment: Paint a parabolic path on the ground and walk it at whatever speed you like.

Answer (score 1):

No. We can construct a counterexample by varying the particle's speed along the parabolic path in some weird way. For example, consider a bead on a parabolic wire, on which we apply a non-constant force as it travels along the trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

An object such as a comet orbiting the sun at exactly its escape velocity follows a parabolic orbit. Its acceleration is certainly not constant.  Its acceleration and velocity decrease with its distance from the sun.

In reality, you would never find an object traveling at its exact escape velocity.